# Some questions about __getattr__ and __getattribute__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, operator-overloading, overriding

The first demo:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = '234'
    # def __getattribute__(self, name):
    #     print('getattr')
    def __getattr__(self, name):    
        print('get')
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print('set')
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        print('del')


b = B()
print(b.__dict__)
b.name
```

`b.__dict__` is `{}`, but the second demo:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = '234'
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('getattr')
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('get')
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print('set')
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        print('del')


b = B()
print(b.__dict__)
b.name
```

`b.__dict__` is `None`, why? And `b.__dict__` invokes `__getattribute__`, but don't invoke `__getattr__`, does it mean `__getattribute__` will prevent from invoking `__getattr__`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `__getattribute__`, `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` methods are called for all attribute access (getting, setting and deleting). `__getattr__` on the other hand is *only called for missing attributes*; it is not normally already implemented, but if it is then `__getattribute__` calls it if it could not otherwise locate the attribute, or if an `AttributeError` was raised by `__getattribute__`.

You replaced the standard implementations of the 3 main methods with methods that do nothing but print and return `None` (the default in the absence of an explicit `return` statement). `__dict__` is just another attribute access, and your `__getattribute__` method returns `None`, and never itself calls `__getattr__` or raises an `AttributeError`.

From the [*Customizing attribute access* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access):

> `object.__getattr__(self, name)`
>   Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for `self`).

and

> `object.__getattribute__(self, name)`
>   Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances of the class. **If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly or raises an `AttributeError`.**

(Bold emphasis mine).

Either call the base implementation (via `super().__getattribute__`) or raise an `AttributeError`:

```
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.name = '234'
...     def __getattribute__(self, name):
...         print('getattr')
...         return super().__getattribute__(name)
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         print('get')
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         print('set')
...     def __delattr__(self, name):
...         print('del')
...
>>> b = B()
set
>>> b.__dict__
getattr
{}
>>> b.name
getattr
get
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.name = '234'
...     def __getattribute__(self, name):
...         print('getattr')
...         raise AttributeError(name)
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         print('get')
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         print('set')
...     def __delattr__(self, name):
...         print('del')
...
>>> b = B()
set
>>> b.__dict__
getattr
get
>>> b.name
getattr
get
```

Note that by calling `super().__getattribute__` the actual `__dict__` attribute is found. By raising an `AttributeError` instead, `__getattr__` was called, which also returned `None`.

Comment: `b.name` don't call `__getattr__` either, but `b` don't have attribute `name`, so why don't call `__getattr__`?

Comment: @gaussclb: `b.name` **does** call `__getattribute__`; `get` is printed.

Comment: It prints `getattr` not `get`, why not call `__getattr__`?

Comment: ah, your second example. Your `__getattribute__` replaced the built-in version, so nothing is calling `__getattr__`.

Comment: `name` is the missing attribute of `b`, so I think `__getattr__` should be invoked.

Comment: @gaussclb: but it isn't, because that's the responsibility of `__getattribute__`. Your implementation *doesn't call it*.

Comment: In my first demo, `b.__dict__` don't call `__getattr__` which means `__dict__` exists, but the second demo, it return `None`, which means `__dict__` not exists, can you give me an explaination in which case `__dict__` exists?

Comment: @gaussclb: no, it returns `None` because you implemented a `__getattribute__` method that **always returns `None`**.

Comment: @gaussclb: `__dict__` exists in both cases, but you broke access to it in the second demo. Use `object.__getattribute__(b, '__dict__')` to see the actual attribute value; that bypasses your broken implementation.